# Can I "wake-up" Heroku server on front-end app launch (seperate deploys)?

Tags: reactjs, express, heroku

I'm aware Heroku sleeps apps after 30 mins of inactivity, and that's fine.

I have a React front-end hosted on Vercel, with an ExpressJS back-end hosted on Heroku, and it's very likely that the user won't need to make a MongoDB call (all this server does) within less than the time it takes to "wake up" the server on Heroku. So if when the app loads it were somehow able to "poke" the server to wake it up, most users wouldn't even know it was sleeping in the first place.

Is this possible without making an intentionally redundant CRUD request?

Comment: No, that's not possible. Just expose a simple `GET /wake` endpoint and have the client hit that.

Comment: can make a get endpoint for test and use cronjob to call it after 30 minutes https://cron-job.org/en/

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-status-monitor You can use this package for monitoring and this will be good to expose as a GET also

Comment: thanks @GermaVinsmoke but im not looking to keep it awake all the time, its not worth it for this. the status monitor looks cool but, if im not mistaken, I can just make a call to `my-url.com/whatever` and even if it returns a 404 it will still wake the server up,

Comment: Yes, I think any call to the server will wake it up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comment from @jonrsharpe under the question, it appears the simplest and easiest way to do this is to just call `get('/wakeUp')` on the initial page load and let it return a 404. Not pretty but it works.

There's no reason this can't also return something more meaningful, but apparently it doesn't need to.